# Подключение к БД Firebird

Tags: android, firebird

Вообще, стоит ли заморачиваться с подключением к базе данных посредством PHP скрипта, или все-таки делать это напрямую из андроид приложения - это не просто моветон?

Очень редко в интернете вижу примеры для фаерберда с использованием коннектора и совершенно не разбираюсь, как связать все это, поэтому, может посоветуете что читать о связи бд с php, и связи php с приложением?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос. Вы планируете использовать android-приложение и удаленную БД на сервере, и спрашиваете стоит ли добавлять сервер-приложение на php или напрямую подключаться к БД. Так или вопрос о другом?

Comment: Да, я именно об этом